# Dual Monitor stuck in Single Monitor mode after power outage

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors running and after booting up my computer from a power outage recently it seems both monitors display the same image rather than being dual. I went to personalization and resolution settings to detect the second monitor but it wouldn't detect. The monitor is obviously working though since it's displaying an image.

Radeon R9 270
2048mb GDDR5 256BIT PCI Express 3.0
- Both monitors are plugged into the same video card
- Both plugged in since boot up

I now see that when checking dxdiag under display the video card isn't displayed.

Just poking around in Device Manager under Display adapters there is a caution exclamation mark in a yellow triangle after going into properties it says:

Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

I go to the drivers tab and click update driver
"Windows has determined your driver software for your device is up to date"

and under resources
"The device isn't using any resources because it has a problem"

Comment: Are both monitors plugged into the graphics card or is, by chance, one monitor plugged into the motherboard?

Comment: They are both plugged into the same video card.

Comment: Have you tried un->reinstalling the drivers?

Comment: About to try a drive rollback, then a reinstallation.

Comment: Uninstalled it, went to AMD to download an autodetected to find out what driver I needed, no supported AMD hardware detected. Is my video card pooched?

Comment: Do you have another 16x or 8x pci express slot you can try?

Comment: Just checked, there seems to be one other pci 16X I can try switching it over, just applying for a job currently so before I mess around with it I'm gonna send that off.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Projector applet by holding the `Windows`key and pressing `P` to cycle until it says `Extend`, then release `Windows`.

edit: re-read your question, adding more upon comment replies

Comment: tried doing windows key + p and nothing happened.